# How to add additional http header to a wp_error rest response

Tags: rest-api, headers, authentication

I'm using the `rest_request_before_callbacks` filter to check for authorization, more or less similar to [this example](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_request_before_callbacks/#comment-4983) from the docs

```
// check if authorization header is set
if ( ! $request->get_header( 'authorization' ) ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'authorization', 'Unauthorized access.', array( 'status' => 401 ) );
}
```

But I'd like to add a [WWW-Authenticate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate) header to the response.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WP_REST_Response` extends `WP_HTTP_Response` class, which has a `header()` method for setting headers.

Using the `rest_request_after_callbacks` filter should allow setting the header, but will need to duplicate the functionality of `WP_REST_Server->error_to_response()`, which at time of writing calls `rest_convert_error_to_response()`, so that's easy enough.

Here's what I think this will end up looking like (untested).

```php
add_filter( 'rest_request_before_callbacks', static function ( $response, $handler, $request ) {
    if ( $request->get_header( 'authorization' ) ) {
        return $response;
    }

    return new WP_Error( 'authorization', 'Unauthorized access.', array( 'status' => 401 ) );
}, 10, 3 );

add_filter( 'rest_request_after_callbacks', static function ( $response ) {
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
        return $response;
    }

    // Only apply to specific error messages.
    if ( 'authorization' !== $response->get_error_code() ) {
        return $response;
    }

    $response = rest_convert_error_to_response( $response );

    $response->header( 'WWW-Authenticate', '' );

    return $response;
} );
```